# documenting a web app

Tags: documentation

My company is trying to improve the UX in our system. It's web based app, full with features.

The system development started 8 years ago, but it was never documented, and our programmers/support team can't remember every small thing about the features, that causes our clients who need support to wait while we dig into the source code to find things.

We want to document it, first for ourselves but later to publish some parts of it to our clients.

Since it's a big app, going through everything without a system/app could take forever and we probably won't be able to cover everything.

I was wondering if anyone knows about such system/app?

I need it to be easy to use for out support/sales teams and for the users but also efficient for the documenting process.

Comment: Documentation is an approach, but mostly likely not the best answer.

Fundamentally what I am hearing is that the system may do something unexpected or unknown, but this is ok if we document it so user or support staff can puzzle out afterwards?  This is not good UX.

This is fairly typical symptom where development team has been able to push their internal complexities back onto the user base unreasonably.

System should behave predictably with clear controls.  User assistance should only provided education on concepts; not the "quirks".

Answer (score 0):

Is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) what you need?

> Doxygen is the de facto standard tool for generating documentation from annotated C++ sources, but it also supports other popular programming languages such as C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D.

Comment: not exactly. the source  code isn't documented at this point, so we can't just take documentation from the source code, we want to write it complicity on our own by going through the UI.

Comment: I am not sure about you want. A software that helps you to read your code, helps to analyze its behaviour and range and then helps to create documentation?